# Terminating OPC Subscription in Prosys OPC UA Java SDK

Tags: java, opc, opc-ua

I'm using **Prosys OPC UA Java SDK** for connecting to an OPC UA server and get some data.

I am creating subscription and settings monitored item to get the data.

However, I'm not able to terminate the subscription, like I can in `node-opcua`.

Does the SDK does not support it, or am I missing something? My colleague has put a question in Prosys forum but no reply yet.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method to call is

```
UaClient.removeSubscription()
```

Also answered at the [forum](http://forum.prosysopc.com/forum/opc-ua-java-sdk/deleting-or-teminating-subscription/#p2299).